# The right way to use use choices in django

Tags: django

I have my choices as follows but i get an error stating 
choices must be an iterable containing actual value and readable name

```
  my model.py


  class mymodel(models.Model):
         MY_CHOICES =(
                     ('corperation1','corperation'),
                     ('Liablility2','Liablility'),
                     )
      Company_type = 
      MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES,max_choices=1,max_length=2)
```

Comment: try it like this 
`class mymodel(models.Model):(
         MY_CHOICES =('corperation1', _('corperation')),
)`

Comment: I did resolve the issue ,I just needed to add an integer in my first string

Comment: I did resolve the issue ,I just needed to add an integer in my first string

Answer (score 0):

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
     company_type = models.CharField(max_length)

class myform(forms.ModelForm):
     company_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = (('corperation1','corperation'),('Liablility2','Liablility')), widget = forms.MultiSelect())
```